# can't load page in development environment Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I was working on my website on the signupaction method, which registers a user. Now all of a sudden, the signup page won't load anymore, the welcome page loads perfectly.

I did not edit code that loads the page, I just edited code when someone tries to signup (i.e. clicking on the form submit button).

I tried to clear the cache but no succes.
I did not include code cause this is clearly caused by something else.

Link I try to acces:

```
http://localhost/SocProNetbeans/web/app_dev.php/signup
```

Route:

```
login_login_signup:
    path:     /signup
    defaults: { _controller: LoginLoginBundle:Default:signup }
```

This link works perfectly:

```
   http://localhost/SocProNetbeans/web/app_dev.php/login
```

This is the code that causes the problem:

```
$teamArr = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getRepository('LoginLoginBundle:Team')
                    ->findAll();
            $check = false;

            while ($check == false){
                foreach($teamArr as $oneteam){
                    if(empty($oneteam->getUserUserid())){
                        $team = $oneteam;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Anything in the logs? Web server logs, app logs?

Comment: if it's in prod mode, why are you using app_dev.php?

Comment: My bad, I mean i'm in development mode

Comment: Found the problem, not sure how I can fix it, but I found it :p

Comment: What's the problem then?

Comment: I can't load my page because of a foreach loop, I don't know whats wrong with this loop

Answer (score 0):

This is an infinite loop:

```
        while ($check == false){ // $check is never true
            foreach($teamArr as $oneteam){
                if(empty($oneteam->getUserUserid())){
                    $team = $oneteam;
                    break; // This only breaks the foreach loop
                }
            }
        }
```

To prevent it from executing infinitely, you *must* manipulate `$check` to have a truthy value or redo your loop.